# How to simplify recurrence relation?

Tags: exponentiation

I'm having trouble seeing how

$$5(2^{n-1} + 5\cdot 3^{n-1}) - 6(2^{n-2} + 5\cdot3^{n-2})$$

simplifies to:

$$2^{n-2}\cdot  (10 - 6) + 3^{n-2} \cdot (75 - 30)$$

How can I simplify the above expression to get to the second version?

Comment: What does that have to do with a recurrence relation?

Comment: Sorry.  It's part of solving a recurrence.  I'm just struggling to figure out how to get the right math syntax to work in my posts, I'll do that today and update this.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $$5\cdot 2^{n-1} = 5\cdot 2\cdot 2^{n-2} = 10\cdot 2^{n-2}, 5\cdot 3^{n-1} = 5\cdot 3\cdot 3^{n-2} = 15\cdot 3^{n-2}$$, and combine like terms.

Comment: hint?${}{}{}{}{}$